# Python/Sikuli 1.0.1 custom test runner

Tags: python, unit-testing, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I am new to sikuli and python 2.4 in general. I have a test case setup as follows:

```
class testCase(unitTest.testCase):
    def setUp(self):
        try:
            #do setup
        except:
            #handle error, trace

    def tearDown(self)
        try:
            #do tearDown
        except:
            #handle error

    def testMethod(self)
        try:
            #do test method
        except:
            #handle error
```

And I'm trying to find a suitable test runner to be able to generate a .xml and a .html test result. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Btw I'm doing try, except because I'm logging the error, and the steps of my test case to an external .log file. I would like to create a suitable test runner in which i can add all my test cases and generate test report .html. Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, the last version of Sikuli Script work on Jython/Python 2.7, not 2.4 . That's way better.

Second, Sikuli Script now is version X1.1.1. (I work with that version myself currently). You better upgrade to 1.1.1 too, as it is more actively developed and supported.

Now a direction -- you may want to look into Sikuli Robot Framework integration: 
http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios.html#using-robotframework

I had a few attempts to run Robot Framework with older version of Sikuli and got impression that RF has a pretty nice test runner and test reporting in html ( http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#report-file ).

Unfortunately RF integration is out of my project priorities now, but if you get any more questions you can ask them on official support forum: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+questions (and maybe I'll try answering them there as well).